# Where can I found the stack of protocols that ICQ using to develop my own client?

Tags: network-programming, tcp, network-protocols, icq

I am going to develop ICQ client and I just wonder where can I find a reference to understand the protocols they used? Any links, books, etc. 
And, by the way, if I am not mistaken - all ICQ clients - QIP, Miranda, ICQ Lite and others - uses the same version of protocol to communicate correctly with ICQ servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[libpurple](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple) is a library that implements lots of IM protocols, among them the oscar protocol used by icq. It is used by many IM clients and is pretty stable, so I recommend you just use it. If you want to understand oscar though, studying libpurple might be a good idea.

Comment: it`s a library implemented in C++, right? so I can use any library in C++ I want to? QT, boost, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has an article on the [OSCAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSCAR_protocol) protocol, although it's proprietary.

Answer (score 0):

Pidgin is open source, perhaps you can refer to its source code.